# Odd DNS behavior, cant access / ping certain external hosts from within home LAN

Tags: networking, dns, home-networking

A family member noticed recently that we cannot access certain websites from within my home network. The two noticed thus far are https://accounts.snapchat.com and https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/. Both of those host names ping fine from outside my network, and open in web browsers. From inside my network I cannot resolve the ip address via nslookup or ping the host. I have tried pinging them directly from the router and I get no response. There are perhaps others that we just haven't encountered yet. These sites were working as of 1 week ago.

I've confirmed the issue on multiple windows PCs and android devices.

Is this the result of a DNS issue, an ip black list, or something else?

Comment: do you have a pihole server? where do your clients point to for DNS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was caused by some sort of dns cache issue in dd-wrt that a soft reboot did not correct. Using the commands here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/how-to-clear-dns-cache-on-dd-wrt I cleared the cache and everything seems to work now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).